# How to define new loop function

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a medhod like this.

```
def run
  loop do
    sleep 0.1
    # do something
  end
end
```

And I want to write it like this.

```
def run
  every 100, :msec do
    # do something
  end
end
```

How can I write a method like this `every`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def every(quantity, units = :sec)
  # this could be improved but you get the idea
  quantity = quantity / 1000.0 if units == :msec
  loop do 
    sleep quantity
    yield
  end
end

every 100, :msec do
  puts Time.now
end
```

Comment: I put `sleep quantity; yield` inside `loop`, then it works. Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to use yield.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer with the loop. Please Vote it up if you like it!